# How do I connect an Orange Pi 4 LTS running Android to Android Studio on a Mac?

Tags: android-studio, adb, orange-pi

I have an Orange Pi 4 LTS booting Orange Pi's Android 8.1 Micro SD image. I enabled developer mode (clicking on the build number in Settings seven times in a row) and enabled USB debugging in the Developer options in Settings. But I can't figure out how to connect to it from Android Studio (Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2) running on a MacBook Pro.

I opened Connection Assistant in Android Studio and tried all three USB-A ports on the Orange Pi 4 LTS (USB 3.0, USB 2.0, and USB 2.0 host). And I tried connecting the USB-C port directly to the MacBook Pro (I guess the Mac provides enough volts & amps). But when I press the Rescan devices button in Connection Assistant, it detects the same number of devices (all of which I recognize) as when the Orange Pi 4 LTS isn't connected to the MacBook Pro.

I also installed the Android SDK platform tools and tried running `./adb devices` from the command-line, but I get "List of devices attached" with an empty list with each of the USB connections I list above.

**Update:** I installed Android Studio on a Windows machine and connected it (via the USB-C port) to the Orange Pi 4 LTS booting the same Android image. Android Studio showed the Orange Pi 4 LTS under "Running Devices" and displayed the screen before and while I ran my app. So we know the problem connecting it to Android Studio on the Mac was not with the Orange Pi 4 LTS.